# Adding Contacts From Skype

Tags: contacts, skype

Here is what I want to do:
In skype I have contacts: A,B,C
In android I use phone memory populated with google contacts: C,D,E
My goal is to display in my contact list users C,D,E with option to call in skype for contact C (as common for both list).
What I do:

- After installing skype: Sync contacts
- A,B,C(skype),C(google),D,E appear in phone contacts
- I merge contact C
- Unmark "show Skype contacts" in phone contacts settings
- Everything works as I want: C(merged),D,E

BUT 
When I restart skype I see the list in phone contacts like: A,B,C(merged),D,E
How can I achieve my goal even after restarting skype?